# Config Set min and max value for window size Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Is there a way to config.set the mininum size and maximun size for a kivy window. For example the following code allows to set the default value when executed and make it not-resizable:

```
Config.set('graphics','width',500)
Config.set('graphics','height',400)
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
```

What I'm looking for is to make it resizable but with a size-limit. I tried to search it on the API but I can't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For setting a minimum size for the window use this section of code:

```py
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (500, 400)
Window.minimum_width, Window.minimum_height = Window.size
```

Answer (score 6):

Before any other kivy imports, set the default kivy graphic values. In most cases, the ideal position is in the `main.py`.

```py
from kivy import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1200')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_height', '600')

import kivy
# ...
```

Check the [API](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html) for other variables.

Comment: Config.set should be used before importing any other Kivy modules. Ideally, this means setting them right at the start of your main.py script

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by overriding the`do_layout` function to check for size changes.
This example checks if the size gets bigger than 500, 400.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyLayout(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def do_layout(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayout, self).do_layout()
        width, height = Window.size
        if width > 500:
            Window.size = 500, Window.size[1]
        if height > 400:
            Window.size = Window.size[0], 400
```

Comment: This answer is useful , but actually the resizing looks too glitchy because it does the resize after the resizing. Is there a way to block the resizing?